# Как сделать такую кнопку в письме?

Tags: html5, email, gmail

Здравствуйте. Зарегистрировал аккаунт в Firefox, и когда получил письмо для подтверждения почты был удивлен, мне не нужно было открывать письмо чтобы подтвердить почту. Как я могу сделать такую кнопку на своих письмах с сайта, может кто знает? Или это Google сам делает некоторым компаниям?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Google* находит и опознает такие письма по ключевым словам (сам, без чьего-либо участия). Так что сделайте письмо таким, чтобы было видно - это регистрация. Если же сайт работает на *WordPress*, можно вообще не беспокоиться на этот счет.

P. S. Данная функция находится в экспериментальном режиме, вероятность распознавания не 100-процентна.